# How did the trend of the elder sister(s) x little brother love affair started?

Tags: tropes

I found this to be called [Not Blood Siblings](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotBloodSiblings) according to TVTropes.

Here are some examples:

> In the anime *Happy Lesson*, Chitose's sisters aren't really related to him and are clearly invoking a Big Sister Instinct and Cool Big Sis, but this isn't milked for UST at all.

> *KissXsis* runs on this trope. Keita's twin stepsisters compete with each other for his affections, much to his dismay. His parents not only are aware of this, but actively encourage him to go for one of the girls, constantly reminding him that "it's not by blood, so it's OK!"

In KissXsis, Ako and Riko literally love their little brother Keita (related by marriage of their mother and Keita's father) and they keep competing for his *Love* in almost every episode.

Freezing also has this: a 2nd year Pandora has to choose a 1st year Limiter, and even though the Limiter calls his Pandora a sister (but not blood related) they perform an initiation "baptism" also known as "first room visit".

Other examples: Kanokon.

Who started this? And what is its inspiration?

Comment: you might be surprised, but it's taken directly from real life

Comment: Didn't find enough info for a full answer but have a look at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FatherIWantToMarryMyBrother if you haven't already.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrotherSisterIncest

Comment: Not everything is a "trope"!

Comment: `I found this trope to be called: Not blood Related` **trope** `according to` **TVTropes**. So its a trope then?

Comment: The word "trope" has a meaning, and that meaning is not "has an article on TVTropes".

Comment: @senshin Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm just asking if this is considered a trope or not. I guess its not and your right about `Not everything is a "trope"` gonna edit my question.